# Lotus note , mail is coming as a attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lotus-notes, mail-server

i am sending mail from my rails application , but in lotus notes is coming as atttot4u.dat.dat file , attachment , but in other mails , like gmail , zimbra it's coming properly ..

this is the header 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Please help me in the same .

Comment: What version of the Lotus Domino server and Lotus Notes client software are you dealing with?

Comment: Hi richard   i am using 8.5.1 lotus notes

Comment: Is the message stored as a MIME message when you read it? Or was it already converted to Notes rich text format by the server before it was stored in the user mailbox?

Comment: Hi Richard , i read this on the server log file ..

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Let me try asking in a different way... If you open the user's mailbox, selec the message, and bring up The Document Properites dialog, then select the Body field in the scroll box on the second tab, is the Data Type set to "Rich Text", or is it set to "MIME Part"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the filename ?
We were having a similar problem with Lotus Notes, receiving *.dat files with weird names, which would change every time we would open the email or its preview.
Finally, removing all kinds of spaces and accented characters did the trick.
[This post](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Attachments_renamed) put us on the right track, even though not Lotus-related.